# PHP displaying items not yet generated with exec

Tags: php, exec

I'm doing some video previewing, and would like to generate previews of the videos as a .gif, where the server has a (changing) collection of videos and previews that go along with each video.

Currently, when a user loads a video, I check if the preview already exists, and if it doesn't, use `exec("ffmpeg" <stuff>)` to create and return them.

Is there a way to display some kind of filler image (such as a image-being-created image) while the server is creating the previews? Alternately, it could display the filler image then call `exec()` to create the images for the next time the page is viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the command in `exec()` to `/dev/null` so that it returns immediately, or else the page is waiting on it to complete:

```
if(file_exists('/path/to/preview.gif')) {
    $image = '/path/to/preview.gif';
} else {
    $image = '/path/to/no_preview.gif';
   //exec('ffmpeg stuf > /dev/null &');
}
//display $image
```

This will work for the next time the page is loaded.  To do it interactively you'll need some JavaScript to check for the file continuously and then load it when it exists.

Or if you don't redirect the `exec()` then you can let it hang the page and then load the new image.